# Merging multiple lines of formatted text into a single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm hoping the answer to this question will get me to the larger question which is a VBA question that I posted on SO.

If I have multiple lines of formatted text and want to merge that content into a single cell, and not lose that formatting, is that possible?

It seems I can either:

1. Paste multiple lines of text into a cell (non formatted).
2. Perform a paste that will generate multiple cells for multiple lines.

However, I want the *combination* of the two.

My underlying issue is attempting to get multi-line HTML into a single cell and keep the formatting through VBA. So far, that hasn't been successful.

Answer (score 0):

This solution has all the elegance of a garbage truck ballet dancing and is as fast as the same truck stuck in rush hour traffic, but it does work:

```
j = 1

For Each myRange In Range1
    If Range0.Value = vbNullString Then
        Range0.Value = myRange.Value
    Else
        Range0.Value = Range0.Value & Chr$(10) & myRange.Value
    End If
Next myRange

For Each myRange In Range1
    For i = 1 To myRange.Characters.Count
        Range0.Font.Name = myRange.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.Name
        Range0.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.FontStyle = myRange.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.FontStyle
        Range0.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.Size = myRange.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.Size
        Range0.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.Strikethrough = myRange.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.Strikethrough
        Range0.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.Superscript = myRange.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.Superscript
        Range0.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.Subscript = myRange.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.Subscript
        Range0.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.OutlineFont = myRange.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.OutlineFont
        Range0.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.Shadow = myRange.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.Shadow
        Range0.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.Bold = myRange.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.Bold
        Range0.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.Italic = myRange.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.Italic
        Range0.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.Underline = myRange.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.Underline
        Range0.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.Color = myRange.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.Color
        Range0.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.TintAndShade = myRange.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.TintAndShade
        Range0.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.ThemeFont = myRange.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=1).Font.ThemeFont
        j = j + 1
    Next i
    j = j + 1
Next myRange
```

Where `Range0` is the range you want to copy the multiple cells to and `Range1` contains all the cells you want to copy (note: `Range0` cannot be a subset of `Range1`)